# Hashmap cannot be cast to firebase user

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm used firebase auth createUser, user created successfully and send user to android client, i want to get Firebase User from user Record but app crashing

[Android Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn9t6.png)

[ِAndroid Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htes3.png)

**Cloud Functions Code:.**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.createAccount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
const userEmail = data.email;
const userPassword = data.password;

return admin.auth().createUser({
    email: userEmail,
    password: userPassword
}).then((userRecord) => {

    return {
        user: userRecord
    }

}).catch((error) => {
    // console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
    if (error.code === "auth/email-already-exists") {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('already-exists',error.message);
    } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument',error.message);
    } else {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: please put code as text

Comment: @bojan ,I have tested on Nexus 5 API 23 and logcat as shown in [Logcat Error](https://e.top4top.net/p_11526wvc21.png)